# How can get context in my Own method or static block?

Tags: android, widget, android-context, appwidgetprovider

I am in `AppWidgetProvider` class. I want to call a static block before any callback method, but I need the context inside my static block. How can I get that?

Below is my code:

```
public class widgetClass extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static
{
// here i want the context

}

    @Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds){
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the static block? Generally it's not possible what you're attempting, although you might be able to use the `Application` context by setting it up with `Singleton`-like access. Perhaps it's an idea to execute the logic in the static block the first time `onUpdate()` gets hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `onEnabled` instead of using a static block.